# Kafka command line producer/consumer have 1 second latency

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I'm doing a test run with Kafka using the command line producer and consumer.

I'm running this in one Terminal window

```
bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic tag7
```

and this in another

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic tag7 --zookeeper localhost:2181
```

but it takes over 1 second for the data that I sent to be printed by the consumer. The data that I'm sending is what I type in to the producer, so basically 1 message every few seconds. Are there any configuration options I can change so that the Kafka broker expects very few messages per second and thus makes the messages move significantly quicker?

I'm using the default configurations of Zookeeper and Kafka, so I haven't configured much.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two configuration parameters for Kafka - one is setting the minimum amount of data received before answering consumer request and the other is setting the maximum amount of time to wait for this data to arrive before answering the request.

You can try to add following options:

```
--consumer-property fetch.max.wait.ms=0 --consumer-property fetch.min.bytes=0
```

For more info:

- Look at this [issue](https://github.com/Jroland/kafka-net/issues/44) for details.
- Check the [kafka consumer configs](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs).

Comment: not sure if it is changed. this does not work. As the other answer says, changing the producer side `--timeout 100` is what helped me.

Answer (score 8):

As the answer from [Ivan Georgiev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6949234/ivan-georgiev) didn't work for me (not only because it is about the consumer and not the producer), I opened [another question here in StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44334304/kafka-spark-streaming-constant-delay-of-1-second/44499482#44499482), and finally also in [Apache's Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-5426) and **[ppatierno](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2210944/ppatierno) (thanks)** answered why it happened and how to solve it.

For changing the console producer's properties `linger.ms` (1000ms by default) and `batch.size` (16384 by default) you need to specify it in the command line with `--timeout` and `--max-partition-memory-bytes` respectively, for example, if you are in the Kafka's main folder:

```
./bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic testConsole --timeout 100
```

Comment: Actually both answers are right. Ivan's answer is how you tune the consumer latency and this answer is how you tune the producer latency. It just happens that there is more room for improvement from the defaults on the producer side. If you do both you should get the best results for end to end latency.

Comment: Yes I know (I am going to add it to my answer, thanks!), the thing is that it is not needed (at least in version 0.10.2.1) to do any tune in the consumer to have less than one second delay which is brought about by the producer.

Comment: Also console-producer defaults to acks=1 which reduces latency but also can lead to message loss so don't get surprised if you see message loss when killing brokers and testing failover when using defaults.